# Getting 404 on custom implementation of ajax call for json file with karma and jasmine

Tags: javascript, ajax, jasmine, karma-runner

I am relatively new to karma and jasmine. I love the syntax but now I'm having an issue with a custom ajax function I wrote:

```
function ajax(options, callback) {
    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                callback(xmlhttp);
            } else if (xmlhttp.status == 404) {
                callback(null, xmlhttp);
            } else {
                callback(null, xmlhttp);
            }
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open(options.method, options.url, true);
    xmlhttp.send(options.data);
}
```

So in my test file:

```
describe('ajax', function() {
describe('$.ajax', function() {
    it('should be able to get data', function(done) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'test.json',
            method: 'GET'
        }, function(data, err) {
            expect(data).toBeDefined();
            console.log(data);
            console.log(err);
            done();
        });
    });
});
});
```

And it returns an xhr object with an 404 error. On closer inspection PhantomJS says: `[web-server]: 404: /test.json`. After searching a few answers I tried proxying, which still resulted in a 404.

Btw this does not use jquery. It is a custom implementation which is set on a $ module that wrote. All of the src code is in vanilla JS.

So how do I get the ajax function to be able to access the json file. My file structure at root is:

```
/
--src 
  --js 
--tests 
--karma.conf.js
```

and i've treid putting the test.json file in src and test directory.

Finally my karma.conf.js:

```
// karma.conf.js
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    reporters: ['spec'],
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    files: [
      'src/js/**/*.js',
      'tests/*.js'
    ]

  });
};
```

And in case you find it relevant this is being handled by Gulp.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i figured it out. It was very confusing and there just isn't a lot of information out there about it. To get access to a json file in your project you need to use the karma.conf.js file. In my case I had to change this:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    reporters: ['spec'],
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    files: [
      'src/js/**/*.js',
      'tests/*.js'
    ]

  });
};
```

to this:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
config.set({
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    reporters: ['spec'],
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    files: [
        'src/js/**/*.js',
        'tests/*.js', {
            pattern: 'tests/*.json',
            served: true,
            included: false
        }
    ],
    proxies: {
        '/tests/': '/base/tests/'
    }

});
};
```

The pattern section is what grabs the json file without throwing horrifying errors. Apparently these are called fixtures?

Notice the proxies part. I'll try to explain it as best as possible. Basically Karma serves everything from a base directory that links to the root of your directory. Now when I say base, i don't mean root or /, its /base/. This is where I got confused.

So if you have a directory you want to serve your `{pattern: 'spec/fixtures/*.json'}` from, you will need a proxy like: `proxies: { '/spec/fixtures/': '/base/spec/fixtures/' }` and then your ajax call in your test will go to the url `spec/fixtures/test.json`.